# Setting up HTTP Load Balancing with Nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress

Could somebody write up the steps of setting up HTTP Load Balancing with [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) for Google Kubernetes Engine?

I followed this [GKE tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) for a basic Ingress. It got a `Forwarding Rule` in `Load Balancing` tab in the end. I guess if I want to delete that `Load Balancer`, I will need to use [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)?

I looked at this [Nginx Ingress GKE tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke), but I don't know how to combine those two tutorials to make the "Hello-app" work without a `Load Balancer`.

Answer (score 1):

**I. If you are using GKE ingress controller**

1)

```
  kubectl run web --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0 --port=8080
```

2)

```
kubectl expose deployment web --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort
```

3)

```
cat <<EOF > ./ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: web
    servicePort: 8080 
EOF
```

4)

```
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
```

5) Wait up to 5 minutes until GKE apllies firewall rules for your ingress

6) Curl your web app

```
curl $(kubectl get ingress nginx | awk 'NR==2{print $3}')
```

**II. If you want to do it with nginx ingress controller**

1)

```
  kubectl run web --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0 --port=8080
```

2)

```
kubectl expose deployment web --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort
```

3)

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress
```

4)

```
cat <<EOF > ./ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: web
    servicePort: 8080
EOF
```

5)

```
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
```

6)

```
curl $(kubectl get svc |grep nginx-ingress-controller|awk '{print $4}')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the write up. With nginx-ingress-controller, step 3 creates a Forwarding Rule in `Load Balancing`. How to not use a Forwarding Rule?

Comment: As long as you will be using GKE LB you'll be getting that Forwarding Rule. MetalLB is an alternative - https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/